# How to select to refcusor from Hash array object in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I can not fetch value from my hash table of object type to refcursor.
Please advice me for your solution.
I have types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE RULE_SET_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
   AR_ID NUMBER (18),
   TMN_CODE VARCHAR2 (8),
   RULE_ID NUMBER (10),
   RULE_PRIORITY NUMBER (3),
   ATTRB_KEY VARCHAR2 (100),
   ATTRB_VAL VARCHAR2 (100)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE RULE_SET_TABLE IS TABLE OF RULE_SET_TYPE;
```

And in my packages, I using as:

```
--In Pack Spec   
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MSV_API
AS

   TYPE REFCURSOR IS REF CURSOR;

   TYPE RULE_HASH_TABLE IS TABLE OF RULE_SET_TYPE
      INDEX BY VARCHAR2 (100);//I can't not create this type at schema level, that cause by declare in package
   .................
-- In Pack Body
PROCEDURE GET_APPY_RULES (P_TMN_CODE   IN     VARCHAR2(8),
                             P_CUR           OUT REFCURSOR)
   AS
      RULE_SET_VAL      RULE_SET_TABLE;//Temp object for data processing
      RULE_SET_RESULT   RULE_SET_TABLE; // 
      RULE_HASH         RULE_HASH_TABLE;//using of hash array type
      K                 VARCHAR2 (100); //
   BEGIN
   ............
   -- OPEN p_cur FOR SELECT * FROM table(RULE_HASH); not working:ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
      RULE_SET_RESULT := RULE_SET_TABLE ();
      K := RULE_HASH.FIRST;
      WHILE K IS NOT NULL
      LOOP
         --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (K || ' : ' || RULE_HASH (K).ATTRB_VAL);
         RULE_SET_RESULT.EXTEND;
         RULE_SET_RESULT (RULE_SET_RESULT.COUNT) := RULE_HASH (K);
         K := RULE_HASH.NEXT (K);
      END LOOP;

      OPEN P_CUR FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE (RULE_SET_RESULT);
   END;
```

My problem is can not fetch data to refcursor from hash array in Oracle. And I convert from hash array to Table of Object by looping. I want to get better solution for this way. ** -- OPEN p_cur FOR SELECT * FROM table(RULE_HASH); not working:ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

I know the fetch data into other collection by looping hash array is not good for performance.

Have any idea for my problems?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To make it easier for people to answer your question, you'll need to make it easier for them to reproduce your problem. I can see at least one definition that is missing from your post, that of FD_APP_RULES

Comment: Thank you for reading.
My problem is can not fetch data to refcursor from hash array in Oracle.
And I convert from hash array to Table of Object by looping.
I want to get better solution for this way.
**
-- OPEN p_cur FOR SELECT * FROM table(RULE_HASH); not working:ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
      
**

Comment: Your ability to eliminate the need for converting an associative array to a nested table depends upon your ability to populate the nested table instead of populating the associative array. You didn't show that part of the code nor did you name the language used to create the program calling the PL/SQL code. You need to do both before you can know how to proceed.